# Android :Notifications are not received while app killed W/GCM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED

Tags: notifications

I'm using oneSignal for receiving notifications and I have observed this one issue that when the app is killed, notifications are not being received and give me this error

> W/GCM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent {
> act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=travel.lemi.dev (has
> extras) }

I have tried several solutions but nothing seems work appropriately plesae help!!

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: android as result cancelled intent

Answer (score 1):

As per oneSignal official documentation,notifications are based on manufaturer of device and they are modify it as they want.(https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-show-successful-but-are-not-being-shown#the-app-is-force-stopped)

To address the broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED issue, One signal official documents suggests that "If you seen this cancelled intent above then your app could not be started to process the notification." (https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-show-successful-but-are-not-being-shown#checking-your-app-state).

To better explaination of this issue is, If app run with signed apk it will not produce error(broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED) but if your app is unverified/unsigned the device will block every background tasks associate with including service/broadcast etc.

we can definietly put the trigger also as per documentation(https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/in-app-message-examples#target-certain-android-manufacturers-and-devices) but i think it is not NECCESSARY.

So If we are using signed apk this issue may not occured in real device.